# SQLite3 query executio issue

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a database file to which I connect through php. I only want to get all the results from the particular table. I know how to connect and query it, but for some reasons I get an array which holds only 1 result, not all the results that are stored in the table. I've checked the PHP SQLite manual, and tried to follow their example. But it wouldnt work.

The table Country holds 10 rows, but i receive only 1. What's the problem? Thanks

```
         $db = new SQLite3('test1.db');
         if($db)
         {
         echo ("connected");
         }
         else
         {
             echo ("not connected");
         }

         $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Country');
         echo '<br></br>';
         echo sizeof($results);

         => 1
```

Comment: There return of [`SQLite3::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php) is a `SQLite3Result object`... a single item that tells sqlite how to retrieve the results... it'll always have an answer of 1 in the event of success.  You can then use the [`fetchArray`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php) iterator to view your actual rows

Comment: Is there any way, I could format that ugly output from var_dump() method?

Comment: var_dump is used only for test purposes. inside the while statement you can do anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need navigate results:

```
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Advice: Read PHP Manual, it's very useful.... :xD